# Make the background/text colour follow another cells background or text colour

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ok so I have a large spreadsheet (so I don't want to have to set each cells colour individually or manually) and I have many cells copying other cells. So for instance I have cells N9, N
3, N80, N117 and so on =IF(N$931="","",N$931) so if there is something in N931 it is copied to N9 and co, else it is blank. I would like to have the ability to make whatever background colour I set N931 automatically be the same background colour as in N9. How will I do this?

Cheers!
Jon

Comment: I believe that this may be impossible the way you have phrased it. But I notice that you say, “I don’t want to have to set each cell’s colour individually or manually.” How is `N931`’s color being set? If it is a conditional format, or if it is set based on the value some other way, you should be able to apply the same mechanism to `N9` and its friends.

Comment: Do you know the [conditional formatting function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx) in Excel? As @Scott says, it can't be based on the color of another cell, but it can be based on the contents of other cells. So that might help you. A trick you can try is to have a cell with the list values White, Red, Green, etc. and you color the cells using conditional formatting based on that contents (although this only works well if you need a limited amount of colors!).

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't set a cell color based off of another cell's color using conditional formatting, or any other front end techniques, you'll have to use VBA.

Assuming that your data, with colors is in Row N and starts at Row 500. Also assuming that your first cell to copy into is N1 and references N500 like `=if(N500="", "", N500)`. Further assuming that you would copy that formula down to N499; the VBA would look like:

```
Sub copyValuesAndFormats()
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim rngPaste As Range


    'Loop from Rows 1 through 499
    For intRow = 1 To 499

        'Set the copy and paste range
        'CHANGE THE SHEET TO MATCH YOURS
        Set rngCopy = Sheet3.Range("N" & intRow + 499)
        Set rngPaste = Sheet3.Range("N" & intRow)

        'Test to see if rows 500+ have a value
        If rngCopy.Value <> "" Then

            'Since it has a value, copy the value and color
            rngPaste.Value = rngCopy.Value
            rngPaste.Interior.Color = rngCopy.Interior.Color

            'If you wish to copy the color of the font as well, uncomment the next line
            'rngPaste.Font.Color = rngCopy.Font.Color
        End If
    Next intRow
End sub
```

If you use this, then no formulas are necessary in N1:N499. They will be blown out anyway by this code.